# Extracting the 7th number from a 13 digit number

Tags: r

I want to extract the 7th number from a 13 digit number.For instance 9111110123341, 0 would be the 7th number and then i would have a if statement saying if the number is between 0 and 5 assign an m to a new column . Is it possible in r?

Answer (score 8):

Don't use text processing functions for numeric operations:

```
extract_digit <- function(x, n) floor(x / 10^(ceiling(log10(x)) - n )) -  
  floor(x / 10^(ceiling(log10(x)) - n + 1)) * 10
extract_digit(9111110123341, 7:10) #extract the 7th to 10th digits
#[1] 0 1 2 3
```

Comment: Ok, I give up, was thinking about a bitwise operation but this one is great

Comment: I am actually not really convinced that not converting to strings is the way to go. This 13-digit number is probably more of a code rather than a number used for numerical computation.

Comment: @Ruben Just for the beauty and usefulness of the A for people needing to work with numbers and not wishing to convert twice. (And if your read carefully the Q you'll see OP wish to test this digit to know if it's in a range after extracting it.

Comment: ok it worked, thanks @Roland

Answer (score 3):

You could try

```
number7 = substr("9111110123341",7,7)
```

Comment: tested it, it works, thanks @Ruben